# Is there a way to commit unchanged object?

Tags: javers

We have the need to commit an Entity in Javers, even if this entity didn't change.

Our goal is to make Javers work as Git, which enables you to commit a file even if it has not been modified...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Git, if you don't change a file it isn't committed.
JaVers works in the same way and creates snapshots only for changed objects.
It's one of the JaVers core features and we are not going to change it.

Comment: In fact I was not clear enough in my question. We are using JGit, which allows to commit unchanged file... And we are trying to replace it by Javers, but this feature is currently blocking us... JGit seems to manage "commits" and "changes" separately.